# Why do the JList and TextArea components not resize using a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

http://pastebin.com/VaaTRsuf

I would like to have the JList and JTextArea resize with the window, but the JPanel stays in the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LogView class extends JPanel and thus unless you change it, it uses JPanel's default layout, FlowLayout. Components held in a FlowLayout-using container do not change size when the container changes size, and so if you want this behavior, you don't need a component Listener -- you just need to change the layout manager for the LogView JPanel to BorderLayout or something similar that allows its held component to expand, that's it.  One line of code:

```
public LogView(final JFrame contentPane) {

  // .......

  setLayout(new BorderLayout());  // add this, that's it
  add(mainPanel);
}
```

Another option is to get rid of mainPanel as it doesn't appear to be necessary at all, to set the layout of your LogView object to be GridBagLayout and to add your components directly to the LogView object.